# How to add condition if in laravel query? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

My function in UserRepository.php is like this :

```
public function displayList($year, $subaccountcode = NULL)
{
    $query = Self::orderBy('programcode')
                 ->orderBy('accountcode')
                 ->findWhere(['year' => $year])
            if(isset($subaccountcode))
                 ->findWhere(['subaccountcode' => $subaccountcode]);
            else
                ;
    return $query;
}
```

I add a condition to check whether subaccountcode exist or not. I tried to like it, but there exist error :

```
 2/2 ReflectionException in Container.php line 809: Class App\Repositories\UserRepository does not exist
```

How can I solve the error?

**UPDATE**

I using a third-party package. I get from here : https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `findWhere()` does. If it's something like `find()` and it returns an object, but not an instance of query builder, then do this:

```
$query = Self::orderBy('programcode')->orderBy('accountcode')->findWhere(['year' => $year]);

if (isset($subaccountcode)) {
    $query->findWhere(['subaccountcode' => $subaccountcode]);
}

return $query;
```

Comment: `$Subaccountcode` exist or not, `->findWhere (['year' => $ year])` must stay be run

Comment: There exist error : `1/1 BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method findWhere does not exist. `

Comment: @mosestoh this method doesn't exist in Laravel, I thought it's method was defined by you. If you did defined it, please show how did you do that. If not, use `where()` instead of `findWhere()` and `return $query->get();` at the end.

Comment: If the query is like this : `public function displayList($year, $subaccountcode = NULL)
{
    $query = Self::orderBy('programcode')
                 ->orderBy('accountcode')
                 ->findWhere(['year' => $year]);
    return $query;
}`, It works. But when I add condition if, it's not working

Comment: @mosestoh when you're using a third-party package you should say this in the question. I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with `andersao/l5-repository` package. I'd recommend you to edit your question and add this info, maybe someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help